# How to add JavaScript code injection on squarespace to change href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-injection, squarespace

I am trying to change the link on my squarespace website by inserting a code injection. I  am adding the following code:

```
<script>
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('eventitem-backlink')[0];
  element.setAttribute('href', '/archive/2017');
</script>
```

However, this does not work as element is undefined. The document.getElementsByClassName call returns a list of length one with the element I want to edit however when I try to extract it, it is undefined.

When I run the following code:

```
 console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('eventitem-backlink'));
 console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('eventitem-backlink')[0]);
```

it produces the following:

[image: screenshot of console]

Comment: sounds like you run your code before the link is in the dom, you could try and wait for the document to be ready by wrapping your code into `window.load = function() { /* code here */ };`

Comment: I tried this however the code does not run at all like this

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS?

Comment: Consider providing a link to the site and page in question. With Squarespace sites, their are a number of factors that are related to issues regarding custom javascript, most notably the template and whether AJAX Loading is available/enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function too early in the process. Try:

```html
<script>
  (function() {

    function fn() {
      var element = document.getElementsByClassName('eventitem-backlink')[0];

      if (element) {
        console.log('element found');  
        element.setAttribute('href', '/archive/2017');
      } else {
        console.log('element not found yet');    
        setTimeout(fn, 200);
      }
    }

    fn();
  })();
</script>
```